# ¿Como mostrar un mensaje o alerta en la pagina web desde un Generic Handler?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar y decirme que estoy haciendo mal o si esto es posible ya que aun no logro mostrar lo que necesito de antemano gracias.

Estoy subiendo un archivo al servidor pero no quiero que realice el postback así que utilizo un fileupload de html un GenericHandler y ajax. La extension ya la valide en el control del fileupload la propiedad accept pero también quiero validar en el generic handler y si la extension no es correcta mostrar un mensaje en una label o una alerta en mi formulario web desde el Generic Handler.

Bueno mi pregunta es: ¿Como mostrar ese mensaje desde el generic handler?

Aqui coloco mi codigo ajax

```js
  $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function() {
            var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
            $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);

            if (fileupload.value != '') {

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/script/GuardarExcel.ashx',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: new FormData($('form')[0]),
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false,
                    success: function() {
                      
                    },
                    error: function() {
                     
                    }
                });


            }


        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<label id="lblArchivo" class=" labelColor btn btn-primary" style="background-color:#5AAAFF; border-color:#5AAAFF" for="fileupload">seleccione archivo
                    <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="fileupload" class="custom-file-input" accept=".xlsx"  />
                    </label>
```

Aquí coloco el código de mi generic handler

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (context.Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            //Fetch the Uploaded File.
            HttpPostedFile postedFile = context.Request.Files[0];



            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
            string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(postedFile.FileName).ToLower();

            if (fileExtension == ".xlsx") // Compruebo que la extension sea la correcta
            {

                string folderPath = context.Server.MapPath("~/Excel_Archivos/" + fileName);
                context.Session["folderPath"] = folderPath;


                postedFile.SaveAs(folderPath);


            }
            else // Aqui quiero mostrar el mensaje en caso de que la extension no sea la correcta pero no logro mostrar nada.
            {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<body>");
                sb.Append("Error de archivo");                    
                sb.Append("</body>");

                context.Response.ContentType = "text/html";


            }

        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tu handler devuelve un error digamos un codigo y en tu funcion ajax error disparas la alerta.

Comment: Hola @MiguelZarate quisiera sacar el mensaje(para mostrarlo en label o alerta) cuando la extensión del archivo no es correcta a través de ajax o directamente desde el handler aunque no se si se pueda directamente desde el handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//en la parte de tu else agrega el httpCodigo y el mensaje de error.

```
var statusCode = 422; //archivo invalido



    context.Response = new HttpResponseMessage
    {
        StatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)statusCode,
                   Content = new StringContent("extension invalida")
    };
```

Para tu cliente la parte de javascript

```
 error: function() {

                    }
```

reescribela mas o menos asi:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
if(jqXHR.status==422)

      {
     alert('extension de archivo invalida');
}
```

como puedes ver solo agregue pseudo codigo pero es para darte una idea de lo que debes hacer.